# How to save a microedition.lcdui.Image object into storage?

Tags: java-me, midlet

How can you save an Image (microedition.lcdui.Image) object into storage?

I have this Image object:

```
Image outImg; //Contains image data
```

I tried the code below to save it to storage but without success:

```
int[] rgb = new int[240*320];
outImg.getRGB(rgb, 0, 240, 0, 0, 240, 320);
ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(bout);
dout.writeInt(240);
dout.writeInt(320);

for (int i = 0; i < rgb.length; i++) {
    dout.writeInt(rgb[i]);
}
bytes = bout.toByteArray();

FileConnection fcOut = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///root1/img.png", Connector.READ_WRITE);
if (!fcOut.exists()) {
    fcOut.create();
}
DataOutputStream out = fcOut.openDataOutputStream();
out.write(bytes);
```

I searched for a solution but didn't find anything useful. How can I achieve this?

Alternatively, is there a way I can convert an Image object to a byte array? So I can use `DataOutputStream` to write the byte array to memory.

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Comment: No. It just created a new img.png file (307,208 bytes) but can't read.
The original image is 8,321 bytes (outImg object is a copy of an image loaded from memory)

Comment: You wrote "can't read". From where? Java ME code? File Explorer?

Comment: I can't open from File Explorer.

Comment: Did you properly close the fcOut stream? Did you try to open the file from Java ME code?

Comment: yes. i have closed fcOut.I thought just because the above code did not convert to byte array of the outImg.

Comment: Did you try to write the file to SD Card? Check FileSystemRegistry.listRoots() and use one of them instead of "file:///root1/"

Comment: I used Netbeans and oracle emulator to run the demo.

Comment: Actually I have written a byte array of a file into memory successfully
FileConnection fcIn = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///root1/img.png", Connector.READ_WRITE);
DataInputStream in = fcIn.openDataInputStream();
FileConnection fcOut = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///root1/imgCopy.png", Connector.READ_WRITE);
if (!fcOut.exists()) fcOut.create();
DataOutputStream out = fcOut.openDataOutputStream();
byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) fcIn.fileSize()];
in.readFully(imageData);
out.write(imageData);
So I thoungt byte array of the previous code is not the data of a image.

Comment: The .png is misleading. An image viewer will not be able to render this file. Use a reverse code in Java ME to read the file and properly set an Image instance.

Comment: "Use a reverse code in Java ME to read the file and properly set an Image instance."
You mean load the image which created by the code on my question into an Image (microedition.lcdui.Image) object. and and try to show it to the demo app?
sorry, I'm not good at english.

Comment: Yes. That is what I meant. :)

Comment: **I have tried**
`FileConnection fcIn = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///root1/imgOut.png", Connector.READ_WRITE);
            DataInputStream in = fcIn.openDataInputStream();
            Image img = Image.createImage(in);`
**And got an exception.**
`java.io.IOException
 at javax.microedition.lcdui.Image.createImage(), bci=77`

Comment: Your code (on this question, at least) is writing two bytes with image width and height. Remove those lines: dout.writeInt(240); dout.writeInt(320);

Comment: I've been tried, the output file simply decreases by 8 bytes. But the result is the same, I can't open from File Explorer.
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: When you say "can't open from File Explorer", do you mean copy/paste it to another folder? Or to view it with an image renderer?

Comment: Sorry, I mean Windows Photo Viewer can't open the file.

Comment: Windows Photo Viewer can't open the file because it is not a valid .png. Take a look at this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1283875/1284073